# Помогите пожалуйста с версткой лого

Tags: html, css

Нужно сверстать такое лого.
Тут много проблем поскольку во-первых у двух слов разный размер `29pt 18pt`.

Вопрос заключается в том как сделать чтобы блок в котором текст и картинка имел высоту которую задает текст а картинка растягивалась на эту высоту без деформации (иначе говоря нужно то, что на картинке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Здесь с другой башней: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/bXejGd

Картинки брал здесь :https://icon-icons.com/ru/

```css
.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.fas {
  font-size: 100px;
}

.touwer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.logo span {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}

.logo p span:nth-of-type(1) {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.logo p span:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <p class="touwer">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
<g>
 <path d="M448,448V192l-32-32h-32V96h-64V64h-32V32c0-17.688-14.328-32-32-32s-32,14.313-32,32v32h-32v32h-64v64H96l-32,32v256
  c-35.344,0-64,28.625-64,64h512C512,476.625,483.344,448,448,448z M192,416h-64v-32h64V416z M192,352h-64v-32h64V352z M192,288h-64
  v-32h64V288z M192,224h-64v-32h64V224z M288,416h-64v-32h64V416z M288,352h-64v-32h64V352z M288,288h-64v-32h64V288z M288,224h-64
  v-32h64V224z M384,416h-64v-32h64V416z M384,352h-64v-32h64V352z M384,288h-64v-32h64V288z M384,224h-64v-32h64V224z"/>
</g>
</svg>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>milan</span>
    <span>holidays</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, то попробуйте что-то вроде:

```
.logo-container>.logo.logo-image+.logo.logo-text>p{text}*2

.logo-container 
   display:flex;
   ....


.logo 
   &-image 
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: ~n em
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, отформатируйте и поясните Ваш код. Внести улучшающую правку можно, нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1006724/edit).